# How to get generic data type from dialect specific type in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, types, sqlalchemy, orm, metadata

I want to create a function that maps dialect-specific DB types to generic sqlalchemy DB types.

For example:
I'm trying to get data types from the OracleDB table and then create a table in MySql DB(or another) using received metadata.
I'm getting dialect-specific column types.

Here is a minimal code to create OracleDB table:

```
create table test_test(id int, num_int number(10), num_float number(10,4), dt date, ts timestamp, str varchar2(100), fl float);

insert into test_test(id) values(1);
```

To receive DB table column types

```
from pprint import pprint
from sqlalchemy import sessionmaker, create_engine

engine = create_engine(...)
session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
session = session()
res = session.execute('select * from test_test where 1 = 2')
columns = res.cursor.description
pprint(columns)
```

Output

```
[('ID', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_NUMBER>, 39, None, 38, 0, 1),
 ('NUM_INT', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_NUMBER>, 11, None, 10, 0, 1),
 ('NUM_FLOAT', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_NUMBER>, 16, None, 10, 4, 1),
 ('DT', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_DATE>, 23, None, None, None, 1),
 ('TS', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_TIMESTAMP>, 23, None, 0, 6, 1),
 ('STR', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_VARCHAR>, 100, 100, None, None, 1),
 ('FL', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_NUMBER>, 127, None, 126, -127, 1)]
```

How can I get generic sqlalchemy column types (String, Integer, etc) instead of dialect-specific ones?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64214225/2144390

Comment: @GordThompson, unfortunately the solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64214225/2144390) won't work for driver-specific data types like `cx_Oracle.DbType.DB_TYPE_VARCHAR`

Comment: @MaxU re: "won't work for driver-specific data types" - If you consider that to be a deficiency in SQLAlchemy's implementation of `.as_generic()` then please open an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues).

Comment: @GordThompson, ok, we'll try to open a new GitHib issue after the bounty is expired...

Answer (score 5):

The `.as_generic()` method added to SQLAlchemy 1.4 via [this pull request](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/pull/5714) can handle Oracle types defined by SQLAlchemy itself at the dialect level …

```py
from sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle import VARCHAR
oracle_type = VARCHAR()
print(type(oracle_type))  # <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.VARCHAR'>
generic_type = oracle_type.as_generic()
print(type(generic_type))  # <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.String'>
```

… but it is not available to driver-level types unless the driver itself implements it:

```py
from cx_Oracle import  DB_TYPE_VARCHAR
cx_oracle_type = DB_TYPE_VARCHAR
print(type(cx_oracle_type))  # <class 'cx_Oracle.DbType'>
generic_type = cx_oracle_type.as_generic()
# AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.DbType' object has no attribute 'as_generic'
```

So, unless cx-Oracle implements such a method (doubtful) you'll probably have to roll your own function to do it:

```py
def cx_oracle_type_as_generic(type_):
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    if type_.name == "DB_TYPE_VARCHAR":
        return sa.sql.sqltypes.String()
    elif type_.name == "DB_TYPE_NVARCHAR":
        return sa.sql.sqltypes.Unicode()
    # … and so on …
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError


from cx_Oracle import  DB_TYPE_VARCHAR
cx_oracle_type = DB_TYPE_VARCHAR
print(type(cx_oracle_type))  # <class 'cx_Oracle.DbType'>
generic_type = cx_oracle_type_as_generic(cx_oracle_type)
print(type(generic_type))  # <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.String'>
```